# Finding percentages of Fields complete in MS_ACCESS

Tags: ms-access

I am creating a new calculated field in Access 2010 using expression builder. I have three fields total. Field One is the primary key, Field Two is a yes/no calculated field called complete, Field Three is the new field I am creating.  The purpose of Field Three is to show the total percentage complete of jobs comparing the yes fields vs the total number of records. I needed help with the expression to put into expression builder.

Comment: To get the total I would use [totalyes of Field Two] /[totalprimarykeys or total Records]

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to do some behind-the-scenes VBA work to figure that one out.  You'll have to open the table and do a record count.  This form will need to be UNBOUND (not linked to a table) and only for display purposes.

Something like this:

```
Dim db as database
Dim rec as recordset
Dim rec2 as recordset

set db = currentdb
'A table of only Yes values
set rec = db.openrecordset("Select PrimaryKey from MyTable where YesField = 'Yes'")
'All values
set rec2 = db.openrecordset ("Select PrimaryKey from MyTable")

rec.movefirst
YesTotals = rec.recordcount

rec2.movefirst
Totals = rec2.recordcount

rec.close
rec2.close
```

Then you can just populate those boxes with the values of YesTotals and Totals, and divide the two to get your percentage.  The above is "aircode" and untested, so if it doesn't work it should at least get you really close.

Comment: Good answer, but I have a suggestion: Statements like `Dim rec As Recordset` can be ambiguous, especially in complex projects that use a combination of DAO and ADO. Therefore it is considered good practice to always qualify such references: `Dim db As DAO.Database`, `Dim rec As DAO.Recordset`, etc..